# Nuget Library to get all types that implement an interface in all assemblies and referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am struggling to find a good answer on this.

I need to scan all the classes that implement an interface `IDomainEvent`.

The problem is that those types are in projects that are not necessarily loaded. For example, if my main assembly is `WebApi`, there is a dependency on `Application`, which depends on `Domain`, which depends on `DomainEvents`

therefore, I don't have an "easy" way to get all the types that implement `IDomainEvent` and are in `*DomainEvents.csproj` projects

**Is there any nuget library that can dynamically navigate through all referenced projects/assemblies and its subdependencies and is able to retrieve all types implementing an interface?**

It happens at startup once, so I'm not too concerned about performance.

PS: The following method returns 0, as expected, because the assemblies are not loaded

```
var allDomainEventTypes =
  AppDomain
    .CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IDomainEvent)) && !t.IsInterface)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possible try something along this lines

```
var definitions = typeof(YourTypeInsideAssembly).Assembly.GetImplementationsOf(typeof(IYourInterfaceType));
            foreach (var definition in definitions)
            {
                //Do you thing with definition.
            }
```

This would require to specify `YourTypeInsideAssembly` for each implementation of the interface. E.G if you have one project which has 3 classes implementing the interface and another which has 4. You would need to specify two classes one for each project.
I think this way you are forcing to load the assembly as well.

P.S

This worked for me previously as well:

```
 var allAssemblies = Assembly
                .GetEntryAssembly()
                .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                .Select(Assembly.Load)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: He might need to use GetReferencedAssemblies() recursively to get all the other assemblies.

Comment: Yep, I need some recursion to get all assemblies and then get the types from those assemblies. The above suggestions won't find the types I need (which are spread across multiple projects not directly referenced by the main assembly). That's why I'm trying to find a library that does that already for a given interface type as input

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything nice.
I've got the following workaround (thanks to [this great article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/07/03/getting-assemblies-is-harder-than-you-think-in-c/))

```
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAllAssemblies(this Assembly rootAssembly)
    {
        var returnAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        var loadedAssemblies = new HashSet<string>();
        var assembliesToCheck = new Queue<Assembly>();

        assembliesToCheck.Enqueue(rootAssembly);

        while (assembliesToCheck.Any())
        {
            var assemblyToCheck = assembliesToCheck.Dequeue();

            foreach (var reference in assemblyToCheck.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                var fullName = reference.FullName;
                if (!loadedAssemblies.Contains(fullName))
                {
                    var assembly = Assembly.Load(reference);
                    assembliesToCheck.Enqueue(assembly);
                    loadedAssemblies.Add(fullName);
                    returnAssemblies.Add(assembly);
                }
            }
        }

        return returnAssemblies;
    }
}
```

It works well as it's capable of "recursively" loading referenced assemblies and therefore I can retrieve all types implementing the given interface.

However, notice that referencing a project does not necessarily mean that the assembly will be referenced if no class from that project is used.

```
var domainEventTypes = 
    typeof(Startup)
        .Assembly
        .GetAllAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IDomainEvent)))
        .ToList();
```